# Wordpress rewrite dynamic url

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, addition

I want to expand my Wordpress site with lots of products per category dynamically. I have a category with url example.com/koelkast page where I retrieve all products from my database with:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$databasetabel =  get_post_meta( $post_id, 'database-prefix', true);

$data = $wpdb->get_results("
SELECT *
FROM  $databasetabel  
LIMIT 0, 100;
");

foreach ($data as $info) {
echo '<a href=wp-content/themes/mytheme/tpl_detailpagina.php?cat='.$databasetabel.'&idnummer='.$info->idnummer.'>'.$info->typenummer.'<br>';
    }   
} else
{ 
?>
```

This works and I get a nice list of all category products. When I click on a link, the detail page has the following url:

https://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/tpl_detailpagina.php?cat=koelkast&idnummer=76

And I use $_GET to receive the right detail information.

But I want it to be for example:
**example.com/koelkast/miele-w3203** where miele-w3203 is the productname.

I've checked lots of tutorials, but I can't get it to work? Do I need to use Wordpress add_query_vars or just rewrite it with my .htaccess file? What is the best approach here?

Comment: as per me using .htaccess is not a good approach, go with the wordpress  flow and queries as well. Which plugin or method you are using to manage the product..??

Comment: Hi Sunil, thanks for your reply. Since I'm the only webmaster I don't manage the products in Wordpress itself and I use the database directly. Are there any good plugins that are made for these situations? And can you give me an advice what I need to add in my functions.php? Thanks!!